# Groovy JsonBuilder not including collection

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I have the following code:

```
    def customers = Customer.findAll()
    def json = new JsonBuilder()
    json {
        customers.each { customer ->
            id customer.id
            name customer.name
            address customer.address
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting that the result is an json array of customers, but instead it only contains 1 customer. Note the customers list contains 2 elements.

I saw some other post mentioning to use something like:

```
customers.collect { 
    Customer c -> [id: c.id, name: c.name, address: c.address]
}
```

But this style does not really fit nicely in the builder. E.g. I have to use colons `:` to assign values.

Is there another approach without creating groovy objects?

Answer (score 0):

No, json is a map, and you need a list of maps. What you are doing with each is re-assigning the id, name and address fields, so you just get the last value.

So you need to `collect` a list of maps together as you have in the question.

Comment: Yes I think so. But as I mentioned I have to mix style. I was hoping there was a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just this.

```
def json = new JsonBuilder( customers )
```

if there are no additional item in `customer` that is not required in the json.

Comment: No there are more fields and some of them should be excluded.

Comment: Then you need `collect` as mentioned in the question and indicated by Tim. BTW is this only Groovy or is it a Grails app you are working on?

Comment: Not Grails. Spring-Boot MVC using Groovy.